# Show/Hide Unique Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 main divs (exactly same format). What I am looking to do is have the 'ratingclick' button display the DIV  box below it's respective div.

e.g. Ratings button 1 opens the unique Div below it.

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="feature">1 
  <div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox()">Ratings</a></div>
 <div class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 1 </div></div>
 ----------  
 <div class="feature">2 
  <div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox()">Ratings</a></div>
<div class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 2 </div></div>
  ---------
<div class="feature">3
<div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox()">Ratings</a></div>
    <div class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 3 </div></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function RatingsBox() {
var x = document.getElementById("ratingsboxDIV");
x.style.display === "none";

 if (x.style.display === "block") {
       x.style.display = "none";
   } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
}

#ratingsboxDIV {
display:none;
min-height:300px;
background-color:white;
padding: 10px;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 800px;
 }
```

Comment: There is no jQuery here.

Comment: `ratingsboxDIV` is also a class. `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Do you want a jQuery solution or a vanilla JS solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to feed the click `event` into the `RatingsBox` function so that you can distinguish the button that the user is clicking and then toggle visibility of the respective `.ratingsboxDIV` element:

```js
function RatingsBox(event) {
   
var ratingsBox = event.currentTarget // Get the current button
.parentNode                          // Get parent of button
.parentNode                          // Get grandparent of button
.querySelector('.ratingsboxDIV');    // Get the ratings box
  
// Toggle visibility of the div via inline styles
if (ratingsBox.style.display !== "none") {
    ratingsBox.style.display = "none";
} else {
    ratingsBox.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

```css
#ratingsboxDIV {
display:none;
min-height:300px;
background-color:white;
padding: 10px;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 800px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="feature">1 
  <!-- Pass event to RatingsBox -->
  <div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox(event)">Ratings</a></div>
  <div class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 1 </div>
</div>
----------  
<div class="feature">2 
  <!-- Pass event to RatingsBox -->
  <div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox(event)">Ratings</a></div>
  <div class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 2 </div>
</div>
---------
<div class="feature">3
  <!-- Pass event to RatingsBox -->
  <div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox(event)">Ratings</a></div>
  <div class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked great. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using jquery. It will find the next sibling that has the class `.ratingsboxDIV` and show/hide it, after clicking on any element with class `.ratingclick`.

We can find all siblings that follow the clicked element by using `.nextAll(".classname")`, this allows you to place other elements between if necessary. If we follow this with `.first()` we prevent it from toggling all subsequent siblings that have this class (your code suggests they may not be in separate parent elements, although I would recommend this).

You could simplify the jquery line to `$(this).next().toggle();` but it wouldn't be as specific / versatile.

```js
$(".ratingclick").click( function() {

    $(this).nextAll(".ratingsboxDIV").first().toggle(); 

});
```

```css
.ratingsboxDIV {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="feature">1 
    <div class="ratingclick">Ratings</div>
    <div class="ratingsboxDIV">This is Div 1</div>
</div>
 ----------  
<div class="feature">2 
    <div class="ratingclick">Ratings</div>
    <div class="ratingsboxDIV">This is Div 2 </div>
</div>
  ---------
<div class="feature">3
    <div class="ratingclick">Ratings</div>
    <div class="ratingsboxDIV">This is Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick jQuery solution.

```js
$(function() {
  function ratingsBox(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this);
    x.parent().next().toggleClass("hidden");
  }

  $(".ratingclick a").click(ratingsBox);
});
```

```css
.ratingsboxDIV {
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature">1
  <div class="ratingclick"><a href="#">Ratings</a></div>
  <div class="ratingsboxDIV hidden">This is Div 1</div>
</div>
----------
<div class="feature">2
  <div class="ratingclick"><a href="#">Ratings</a></div>
  <div class="ratingsboxDIV hidden">This is Div 2</div>
</div>
---------
<div class="feature">3
  <div class="ratingclick"><a href="#">Ratings</a></div>
  <div class="ratingsboxDIV hidden">This is Div 3</div>
</div>
```

On Click event, we prevent the link from performing it's default action. We then can make use of `.toggleClass()` to easily add or remove a class. This allows us to show or hide the next div. To select the next div, we use `.parent()` and then `.next()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you like jQuery, you may consider adding the UI Library: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

https://codepen.io/seunggabi/pen/aQxZZK

```js
  function RatingsBox(no) {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("ratingsboxDIV");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(item, index) {
    // because of toggle
    if(index+1 === no) {
      return;
    }
      item.style.display = "none";
    });

    var target = document.getElementById("ratingsboxDIV"+no);
    target.style.display = target.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
  }
```

```css
.ratingsboxDIV {
  display: none;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">1 
<div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox(1)">Ratings</a></div>
<div id="ratingsboxDIV1" class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 1 </div></div>
----------  
<div class="feature">2 
<div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox(2)">Ratings</a></div>
<div id="ratingsboxDIV2" class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 2 </div></div>
---------
<div class="feature">3
<div class="ratingclick"><a onclick="RatingsBox(3)">Ratings</a></div>
<div id="ratingsboxDIV3" class="ratingsboxDIV"> This is Div 3 </div></div>
```